# KrakenD HTTP 405 Error When Polling with OPTIONS

Tags: cors, krakend

I get an HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed error every time I make an OPTIONS request to my REST service via a KrakenD API Gateway. It happens whenever I try to request the `/apexadapter/version` endpoint of my REST service. I do not get the same error when I request the same resource directly from the API server (i.e. when I circumvent the KrakenD API gateway).  **I don't understand why I am getting this, and I would like your help understanding what Kraken is doing such that my request is throwing an error.**

I added the `security/cors` into the global extra_config based on an article I read titled [Enabling Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS).

Here is the curl command to simulate my request:

`curl --location --request OPTIONS 'http://localhost:30000/apexadapter/version'`

My krakend.json file has the following:

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "timeout": "15m",
  "cache_ttl": "300s",
  "output_encoding": "json",
  "name": "apexadapter",
  "extra_config": {
    "security/cors": {
      "allow_origins": ["*"],
      "allow_methods": ["GET", "HEAD", "POST", "OPTIONS", "PATCH", "DELETE"],
      "debug": true
    }
  },
  "endpoints": [
    {
      "endpoint": "/apexadapter/version",
      "method": "GET",
      "output_encoding": "no-op",
      "backend": [{
        "url_pattern": "/version",
        "method": "GET",
        "encoding": "no-op",
        "host": [
          "http://apexadapter.apex.svc.cluster.local:38295"
        ]
      }]
    },
   ... and so on
```

And here is the result output by Postman (my tool of choice to test my API)

```
OPTIONS http://localhost:30000/apexadapter/version: {
  "Network": {
    "addresses": {
      "local": {
        "address": "::1",
        "family": "IPv6",
        "port": 51269
      },
      "remote": {
        "address": "::1",
        "family": "IPv6",
        "port": 30000
      }
    }
  },
  "Request Headers": {
    "user-agent": "PostmanRuntime/7.29.2",
    "accept": "*/*",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
    "postman-token": "bf91c1ff-85fe-41e1-ad17-33afee354b2c",
    "host": "localhost:30000",
    "accept-encoding": "gzip, deflate, br",
    "connection": "keep-alive"
  },
  "Response Headers": {
    "content-type": "text/plain",
    "date": "Fri, 12 Aug 2022 19:40:38 GMT",
    "content-length": "22"
  },
  "Response Body": "405 method not allowed"
}
```

I notice that the response headers in the response are complete stripped. None of my `Access-Control-Allow-*` headers are being returned despite the no-op .

Edit: I have opened an issue with the maintainers: https://github.com/krakendio/krakend-ce/issues/545

Comment: Do you have an endpoint section in your *krakend.json* file with **"method": "OPTION"**?

Answer (score 1):

In extra config just add auto_options : true.

So for example like this:

```
{
   "extra_config": {
    .
    .
    "router": {
        "auto_options": true
    }
}
```

This will attach to each of your requests option method. What you have is not related to the cors issue. :)

Answer (score 0):

This doesn't sound like a CORS-specific issue, since those show up in the client as errors indicating invalid or nonexistent CORS response headers.

Given the **HTTP 405 Method Not Allowed** error message, your problem is almost certainly that your web server is not set up to allow OPTIONS requests at all: most web servers (e.g. Apache) only allow the GET and POST request methods by default, and their configuration must be changed to allow OPTIONS requests as well.

Once you allow OPTIONS requests, then depending on whether or not your CORS configuration is correct, your application will work or will send CORS-specific error messages to the client, which you should be able to figure out.

Comment: OP states it is possible to make a successful call to the web server when the API gateway is bypassed.

Comment: At which point the problem lies with the API gateway itself not allowing OPTIONS requests. I don't know anything about Kraken, but a 405 response isn't a CORS issues per se - it's a problem with OPTIONS requests 'in general' being disallowed.